# increase maximum connections limit for Jetty in Dropwizard

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

After every request to my Restful API the count param increase by as per the metrics details

```
"org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory.8080.connections": {
    "count": 7,
    "max": 81.82049337000001,
    "mean": 69.48544755142858,
    "min": 60.831599733000004,
    "p50": 67.457106916,
    "p75": 74.929439363,
    "p95": 81.82049337000001,
    "p98": 81.82049337000001,
    "p99": 81.82049337000001,
    "p999": 81.82049337000001,
    "stddev": 7.3646953505809565,
    "m15_rate": 0.026533121936096183,
    "m1_rate": 0.0039290853883241165,
    "m5_rate": 0.006899155666327853,
    "mean_rate": 0.003308447398793327,
    "duration_units": "seconds",
    "rate_units": "calls/second"
}
```

After serving 20 requests it stops to serve more requests.

How to increase maximum connections limit for Jetty in Dropwizard.

Comment: [Dropwizard Configuration](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#connectors)

acceptQueueSize: 1024

configuration.yml

Comment: "stops to serve more requests" needs clarification.  As this is rarely ever the case.